# IE not following style rules

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Creating a Wordpress-driven site for a client - http://www.2sleeptight.com

It looks OK in major browsers, except there are some serious problems in IE.   Navigation will not display horizontally and the site title is the wrong color.   There are 2 stylesheets, style.css (main style sheet) and custom.css (edits I have made to style.css)

The Wordpress theme even injects the title color style directly into the page header here:

```
#header .site-title a {font:bold 60px/1em 'Rancho', arial, sans-serif;color:#ffc600;}
```

But IE still picks up that grey color somewhere.

Comment: @iced 10%? Try over 33%. [According to quirksmode it's actually still the second most used browser](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/12/browser_stats_f_5.html). I may hate IE, but I still make sure all my websites are accessible in it.

Comment: I'd say 10% is too big. there are lots of different statistics published around. I don't trust them as virtually no one explains how they measure it. What I do trust is logs of 2 projects, I have access to ATM.

1. EU-facing site for girls. 20-30K uniqs/day, 11% IE.
2. World wide site for developers. 4-5K uniqs/day, NO IE AT ALL.

Comment: @iced Your single- and not-especially-large- site stats aren't remotely an argument against StatCounter's numbers. (Or any major service, really.) What questions do you still have [about their methodology](http://gs.statcounter.com/faq)? And a low-traffic "site for developers" is the *worst* example you could possibly come up with for a recommendation about a consumer site's browser support.

Comment: I trust my own data and don't trust any hipster counters used on hell knows where.

Answer (score 0):

spogue, the problem is the order of your CSS. The values are being inherited by your other CSS files and because they are executed last they become the master.

Simply add this to the bottom of your CSS file.

```
.site-title a {color:#FFC600!important;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but Im not sure it's that simple.  I added your code to the bottom of both stylesheets but it's still the same in IE.  .site-title is defined directly in the page header after the style sheets are loaded.  That should get the final say, but it doesn't.   And why is it bad only in IE?

Comment: Hmmm..   Actually, I was wrong, custom.css is called last.  But now I notice that rules I put there are not being applied.

Comment: because its inherited from another h1

Comment: add the a after .site-title (my bad) I've updated the code in answer.